# Meta-interpreter for calculating max recursion depth

Tags: recursion, prolog, metaprogramming, prolog-metainterpreter

I'm trying to write a meta-interpreter in prolog for prolog, which would return maximal reached recursion depth in a given prolog program.

This code actually counts number of all recursive calls in a program:

```
rc( true, 0) :- !.
rc( ( Goal1, Goal2), N) :- !, %we have multiple goals
  rc( Goal1, N1), %count recursive calls in Goal1
  rc( Goal2, N2), %count recursive calls in goals Goal2
  N is N1 + N2. %add both counters

rc( Goal, N) :-
  clause( Goal, Body),
  functor( Goal, F, A), %get functor and airity
  rcount( F/A, Body, NF), %count calls of that functor/airity in the body
  rc( Body, NB), %recursively process the body
  N is NF + NB. %add counters
```

I must somehow keep track of each individual recursion path and compare their depths, but have problems defining this in prolog. Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
solve(true, 0) :- !.
solve(Head, Hdepth) :- clause(Head, Body), solve(Body, Bdepth),
    Hdepth is Bdepth + 1.
solve((Goal1, Goal2), Depth) :- solve(Goal1, Depth1), solve(Goal2, Depth2),
    Depth is max(Depth1, Depth2).
```

Comment: I think you are missing cut (!) in first solve: solve(true, 0) :- !.
Tnx for the solution. It's actually easier than I thought :)

Comment: `solve(true, 0)` is a simple true fact. No cut is needed. This is pure Prolog!

Comment: But, when backtracking, it will try to match Head with true and Hdepth with 0 and succeed (second solve/2). Which is wrong, you want it to stop when it reaches solve(true, 0).

Comment: What? Why should it match Hdepth with 0? Hdepth will typically be a free variable when solve/2 is called and is still to be computed.

Comment: I would prefer not to have the cut. However, SWI Prolog gives on backtracking "ERROR: clause/2: No permission to access private_procedure `true/0'". This can be avoided with the cut. The logical justification would be that there is surely only one solution.

Comment: OK, avoiding this error is a different and valid reason. You can still avoid the cut by using for example catch/3 or other built-in predicates to see whether clause/2 can safely be used in the second clause. Regarding the "only one solution": A good declarative solution would be, instead of using the built-in clause/2, to represent programs that are to be interpreted in a way that is not defaulty, for example like my_clause(Head, [G1,G2,...,G_n]) ("true" then corresponds to the empty list). Then the meta-interpreter can be written nicely without cuts, and could easily interpret itself as well.